# Azure Devops with Git only suggest Pull Request for latest commit

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

we have recently switched to Git inn Azure Devops (from TFVC) and I am struggling with Pull Requests:

1) I created one branch from Master and committed some changes on that branch. I did *not* do a Pull Request at this time.

2) Then I created a second branch from Master (without the first branch's changes!). I committed changes on that second branch.

Now I wanted to create a Pull Request for the first commit. 
But in Azure Devops, I only get suggestion to create a Pull Request for the latest commit!
I can't find anyway to create a Pull Request for the first commit, unless I first do the second (which I did not want to do in this case).

Is my way of working not supported by Azure Devops with Git?
(I assume this can be done with command line Git, but I would like to avoid that when I'm already working in Visual Studio and Azure Devops.)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: IIRC : from the "branches" screen, there is a link "create pull request" next to each branch. If it is not visible on the base screen, it should appear when you hover on a branch.

Comment: otherwise : @AlbertoP wrote a correct response, which works in all situations. Clicking on a "create pull request" link is simply a shortcut that prefills some of the values in this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to figure out what was the real question but you can always create a new pull request from the menu on the left "Repo → Pull Requests → New Pull Requests" and there you can select the source and destination branch.

If I slightly caught the underneath problem: You can't make a pull request for a single commit in a source branch that have more than one. Pull request operate at branch level, and if you open a pull request you can always add new commit until the PR is closed (merged or abandoned).

Comment: Thanks, I agree that the question was a bit fuzzy :-)

Found the way to do it now!